# Not able to create an instance of class , crashing the app

Tags: ios, swift

SOLUTION FOUND - credit Sanzio Angeli, used `lazy var`

Trying the access the pageIndex in order to update the page indicator , i try and create an instance of a class which has the public property of pageIndex, but the moment i try and do so its crashing the app, can any on one please suggest where i am doing wrong, Strange enough if i do not declare the instance globally but inside a method, the app does not crash

Error i get - `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeeebccea8)`

Below is class whose instance i am trying to create and after that the class where i am trying to call it by creating a global instance at top, i am trying to use it in `func moveToNext()`

```
import UIKit

class ContentViewController: UIViewController {
    let contentDesign = ContentView()
    var pageIndex = 0
    var pageHeading = ""
    var pageContent = ""
    var pageImage = ""
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(contentDesign)
        contentDesign.pagerContent.text = pageContent
        contentDesign.pagerHeader.text = pageHeading
        contentDesign.pagerImage.image = UIImage(named: pageImage)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

}
```

//////---------

```
class MasterView: UIViewController {
    
    var container = UIView()
    var lowerCotainer = UIView()
    var pageNumbering: UIPageControl = UIPageControl()
    var nextButton = UIButton()
    var skipButton = UIButton()
    var pageController = PageViewController()

    **var content = ContentViewController()**

    override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
      
           commonInit()
       }
    
    func commonInit()
    {
        container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(container)
        container.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width).isActive = true
        container.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.6).isActive = true

    }

    @objc func moveToNext()  {
   //  let index = pageController.currentIndex
        let index = content.pageIndex
        pageNumbering.currentPage = index + 1
                   print(index)
                   switch index {
                   case 0...1:

                       pageController.forwardPage()


                   case 2:
            self.view.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    
                   default:
                       break

                   }
    }

}
```

Where the app crashes is strange here in another class at  `var pagerHeader = UILabel()`

```
import UIKit

class ContentView: UIView {
    
    var pagerImage = UIImageView()
    var pagerHeader = UILabel()
    var pagerContent = UILabel()
   let master = MasterView()
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func commonInit()
    {
        pagerImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(pagerImage)
       
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: What line does it crash on?

Comment: great question, now i see it crashes on another class, i updated the question and also posted a image of errors, all seems to be at init , thanks

Comment: Strange enough if i do not declare the instance globally but inside a method, the app does not crash

Comment: glad you found the issue!

Comment: but how to overcome it ?

Comment: I need the global instance else the value is reset to original every time i try and call the method, and why is it crashing , other times creating an instance of class globally does not crash the app

Comment: You have pasted way too much code to sift through, and still have not specified on what exact line your app crashes at. Try and narrow down the problematic code, and make a note of your recent discovery in the question to highlight what you have done to try and fix the issue. That will allow others to better help you.

Comment: @SanzioAngeli - i am really sorry , i did not mean to make you angry, i will try to remove unwanted code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220604/discussion-between-sanzio-angeli-and-multiverse).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working with multiverse:

```
lazy var content = ContentViewController()
```

Instead of:

```
var content = ContentViewController()
```

Has fixed the issue